# firefox PKCS11 WebExtesion "An unexpected error occurred"

Tags: javascript, firefox, smartcard, pkcs#11, eid

I am working on developer mozzilla v58 with my smart eid card.

I call this code:

```
var pkcs11 = browser.pkcs11.installModule("linux_pkcs11");
```

My menifest is setup corretly, it finds the library, but it return error code:

[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIPKCS11ModuleDB.addModule]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://browser/content/ext-pkcs11.js :: installModule :: line 76"  data: no]

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you called "installModule()", you should firstly verify, if Module is not already installed with function: "isModuleInstalled()"

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, you should be able to accept your own answer after a while.